# Data table in R: Counting NA values in columns by using column index

Tags: r, data.table

I have data.table G with columns A, B, C:

code below counts NA values in the column A:

```
G[is.na(A), .N]
```

But when I try to use Column index(For column A index = 1) - I see no result:

```
G[is.na(.SD), .N, .SDcols = 1]
```

How can I fix this problem correctly?

Comment: Please include sample data in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can get the count from the 'j' itself.

```
G[, sum(is.na(.SD)),  .SDcols = 1]
```

and if there are multiple columns, loop through the columns and get the `sum` of NA elements

```
G[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(is.na(x))), .SDcols = 1:2]
```

Comment: you answered my question here and now it works , just the last part is not right. if you wish that i accept your code, just make an `identical(youroutput, myout)`  if it is true it is ACCEPTED http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039915/how-can-i-manipulate-a-very-large-list