# how can I manipulate a very large list

Tags: r, list

I have over 10000 files. I first set my directory to the folder that the files are there.

Then I make a link to the all files with `.txt` format like this

```
filenames <- list.files("path to the file", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE)
```

Then I read it with `fread`

```
ldf<- lapply(filenames, FUN=fread, header=TRUE)
```

Why fread? actually when I use `data.table` , it messes up for example then i must add `sep","`and `row.names=FALSE`etc . If you know a better way, go ahead and advise please. In any case

After i did this, I end up with a huge list which I need now to extract data from it. As an example, I tried to make a representative data below

Of course in real data, there are way much more columns in each file, there only three named `check`and `myfile`and `Myname`

Now I tried to keep only column `myfile`and `Myname` by the following command which did not make it.

```
t<- lapply(ldf, `[`, c(2,3))



 my.list <- list(structure(list(check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), myfile = c("", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R11]", "1xOxidation [M7]", 
"", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R11]", ""), myname = c("Q9Y383", "Q9Y383", 
"Q9Y383", "Q15366-2", "Q15366-2", "Q15366-2")), .Names = c("check", 
"myfile", "myname"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame")), structure(list(
    check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    ), myfile = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Myname = c("F8W727", 
    "O76021", "P46783", "P35527", "Q96C45", "Q9Y383", "Q9Y383"
    )), .Names = c("check", "myfile", "myname"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")), 
    structure(list(check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), myfile = c("", 
    "2xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R6; R8]; 1xCarbamidomethyl [C4]", 
    "", "", "", "1xCarbamidomethyl [C1]", "", "", "", "", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R6]; 1xCarbamidomethyl [C5]"
    ), myname = c("P39019", "A2A3R5; P62753", "Q8IYB3; E9PCT1; M0R088; A9Z1X7; Q8IYB3-2", 
    "S4R3J4; O43390-3; B4DT28; O43390; O43390-2; O60506; O60506-2; E7ETM7", 
    "P07910-4; B4DY08; G3V4C1; P07910-2; G3V4W0; P07910; G3V5V7; P07910-3; G3V2D6; G3V2Q1", 
    "D6R9X9; D6RG19; P61927", "Q00839", "G3XAD8; H0YGI8; P31948; F5H0T1", 
    "Q8IYB3; E9PCT1; M0R088; A9Z1X7; Q8IYB3-2", "P42766", "Q9NX58; D6RDJ1"
    )), .Names = c("check", "myfile", "myname"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -11L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")), 
    structure(list(check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), myfile = c("", 
    "", "", "", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R7]", "", "", "", "3xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R1; R7; R10]", 
    "", ""), myname = c("P61247", "P39019", "Q9NWH9", "P62917", 
    "P62917", "E9PCT1", "Q15149", "Q14152", "Q14152", "Q15020", 
    "Q02543")), .Names = c("check", "myfile", "myname"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -11L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

What do I want?

I want to check whether I have myfile and myname in all files I loaded ? and then have a output like this

```
  file1                file2                  file3                 file4
myfile   myname       myfile   myname      myfile   myname     myfile   myname 
 info     info         info      info        info    info       info     info
```

To make it more reproducible. I want the example data output to be like below

```
    myout<- structure(list(myfile1 = structure(c(NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R11]", 
"1xOxidation [M7]"), class = "factor"), Myname1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("Q15366-2", 
"Q9Y383"), class = "factor"), myfile2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Myname2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("F8W727", "O76021", "P35527", 
"P46783", "Q96C45", "Q9Y383"), class = "factor"), myfile3 = structure(c(NA, 
3L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L), .Label = c("1xCarbamidomethyl [C1]", 
"1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R6]; 1xCarbamidomethyl [C5]", "2xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R6; R8]; 1xCarbamidomethyl [C4]"
), class = "factor"), Myname3 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 
4L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 9L), .Label = c("A2A3R5; P62753", "D6R9X9; D6RG19; P61927", 
"G3XAD8; H0YGI8; P31948; F5H0T1", "P07910-4; B4DY08; G3V4C1; P07910-2; G3V4W0; P07910; G3V5V7; P07910-3; G3V2D6; G3V2Q1", 
"P39019", "P42766", "Q00839", "Q8IYB3; E9PCT1; M0R088; A9Z1X7; Q8IYB3-2", 
"Q9NX58; D6RDJ1", "S4R3J4; O43390-3; B4DT28; O43390; O43390-2; O60506; O60506-2; E7ETM7"
), class = "factor"), myfile4 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA), .Label = c("1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R7]", 
"3xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R1; R7; R10]"), class = "factor"), Myname4 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L), .Label = c("E9PCT1", 
"P39019", "P61247", "P62917", "Q02543", "Q14152", "Q15020", "Q15149", 
"Q9NWH9"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("myfile1", "Myname1", 
"myfile2", "Myname2", "myfile3", "Myname3", "myfile4", "Myname4"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

NEW REQuest

Then I want to split the data into two dataframe. One is keeping only those mynames that their myfile has special strings called `df1`and one those mynames that their myfiles do not have anything or not those special strings

```
df1<- structure(list(myname1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"Q15366-2", "Q9Y383"), class = "factor"), myname2 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA), myname3 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("A2A3R5", 
"D6RDJ1", "P62753", "Q9NX58"), class = "factor"), myname4 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "P62917", "Q14152"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("myname1", 
"myname2", "myname3", "myname4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))


df2 <- structure(list(myname1 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Q15366-2", "Q9Y383"), class = "factor"), 
    myname2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "F8W727", "O76021", "P35527", "P46783", 
    "Q96C45", "Q9Y383"), class = "factor"), myname3 = structure(c(29L, 
    33L, 11L, 18L, 1L, 34L, 35L, 22L, 6L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 4L, 
    10L, 27L, 7L, 2L, 25L, 15L, 24L, 16L, 26L, 13L, 14L, 8L, 
    9L, 31L, 8L, 9L, 31L, 32L, 17L, 3L, 28L, 12L, 33L, 11L, 19L, 
    5L, 34L, 30L), .Label = c(" A9Z1X7", " G3V4C1", " H0YGI8", 
    " O60506-2 ", "A9Z1X7", "B4DT28", "B4DY08", "D6R9X9", "D6RG19", 
    "E7ETM7", "E9PCT1", "F5H0T1", "G3V2D6", "G3V2Q1", "G3V4W0", 
    "G3V5V7", "G3XAD8", "M0R088", "M0R088 ", "O43390", "O43390-2", 
    "O43390-3", "O60506", "P07910", "P07910-2 ", "P07910-3 ", 
    "P07910-4", "P31948", "P39019", "P42766", "P61927", "Q00839", 
    "Q8IYB3", "Q8IYB3-2", "S4R3J4"), class = "factor"), myname4 = structure(c(4L, 
    3L, 10L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "E9PCT1", "P39019", "P61247", "P62917", "Q02543", "Q14152", 
    "Q15020", "Q15149", "Q9NWH9"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("myname1", 
"myname2", "myname3", "myname4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-41L))
```

Comment: `my.list` throws error.

Comment: `Error: unexpected '<' in:
"c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     -11L), clas"`

Comment: @akrun why did you again remove your answer !!!!

Comment: Why add `NA` values to the second data table only? Also, adding blank spaces is not the best way to structure R objects.

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune it is not a problem. if it is NA or NAN or ZERO . all empty places can be NA or NAN or ZERO or blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach. You can change column names after and make other extra cosmetic changes that you like. This is intended to get to the core of your issue, you can dress it up how you like. I wrote a helper function `add_rows` that takes three arguments; a data frame, number of rows to add, and what to fill them with.

```
library(data.table)
#version 1.10+

#Helper function to add extra rows
add_rows <- function(DT, n, fill='') {
  rbindlist(list(DT, data.table(myfile=rep(fill,n), Myname=rep(fill,n))))
}

#Remove first column 
lst2 <- lapply(my.list, function(x) x[, c("myfile", "myname")]) #if using version <= 1.9.8, x[, -1, with=FALSE]

#data table with most rows
len <- max(sapply(lst2, nrow))

#Add rows
lst3 <- lapply(lst2, function(x) add_rows(x, len-nrow(x)))

#Order rows
#braces have backslashes added because without them those characters have special meaning in searches
tofind <- c("13C\\(6\\)15N\\(4\\)", "13C\\(6\\)")
lst4 <- lapply(lst3, function(DT) {
  pattern <- paste0(tofind, collapse="|")
  moveup <- DT[, grep(pattern, myfile)]
  myorder <- c(moveup, setdiff(1:nrow(DT), moveup))
  DT[myorder]
})

#Combine data
newdf <- do.call('cbind', lst4)

#Update names
setnames(newdf, paste0(names(newdf), rep(1:table(names(newdf))[1], each=2)))

newdf
```

Comment: Nice, I did not know that indexing with `-1` works so I was attempting to `bind_cols()` and do something like `new_df[c(F, T, T)]`...

Comment: I will edit that. I just remembered that you switched to `data.frame` for the example because of the posting issue. You are actually working with data tables.

Comment: Did you see the alternate that I wrote next to it in my answer?

Comment: Because the code is built for the 3 columns as in the example.

Comment: You can put the names in directly `x[, c("myfile", "myname")]`

Comment: You can use `setnames(newdf, paste0(names(newdf), rep(1:table(names(newdf))[1], each=2)))` to reset the names. I added it to the answer.

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune ok, I close that one sorry for trouble

Comment: I added the row orders.

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune you really deserve 10 like, Do you want I like other answer of yours? THANKS Man

Comment: No that is not allowed. I believe you can add extra points to this solution as a bounty later. But the minimum is 50. The best way to send thanks is to come back and help others as you grow as a user. It's rewarding to see others make great things happen with R :)

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune Unfortuantly I don't think that I am capable to help anyone because I am stuck with my won problem and seems like I cannot help myself :-(((( since last night until now is about 12 hours I am trying to split the data into two part , I even could not progress a bit. I explained it above . How can I make this question bounty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130201/discussion-between-pierre-lafortune-and-nik).