# dput of a list is giving error

Tags: r, list

I have tired to make an example here [how can I manipulate a very large list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039915/how-can-i-manipulate-a-very-large-list)

I cannot figure out why my dput is giving always error. This is the dput

```
my.list<- list(structure(list(check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), myfile = c("", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R11]", "1xOxidation [M7]", 
"", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R11]", ""), Myname = c("Q9Y383", "Q9Y383", 
"Q9Y383", "Q15366-2", "Q15366-2", "Q15366-2")), .Names = c("check", 
"myfile", "Myname"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103006b78>), structure(list(
    check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    ), myfile = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Myname = c("F8W727", 
    "O76021", "P46783", "P35527", "Q96C45", "Q9Y383", "Q9Y383"
    )), .Names = c("check", "myfile", "Myname"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103006b78>), 
    structure(list(check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), myfile = c("", 
    "", "", "", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R7]", "", "", "", "3xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R1; R7; R10]", 
    "", ""), Myname = c("P61247", "P39019", "Q9NWH9", "P62917", 
    "P62917", "E9PCT1", "Q15149", "Q14152", "Q14152", "Q15020", 
    "Q02543")), .Names = c("check", "myfile", "Myname"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -11L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103006b78>))
```

and this is the error

> Error: unexpected '<' in: "s = c(NA, 
>                                                                                                                                                                                    -11L), class = "

Comment: I think you want to remove `, .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103006b78>)` in the final line. I could see a data.table object with 11 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: @jazzurro why? it is generated by R itself, however, when i remove that I still get error but another type :-p I shared my data in the other post, if you want you can look it up

Comment: I checked `mylist` in your previous post now. Once again, I removed the last part, and I could see 11 rows and 3 columns. I meant 3 columns in my previous comment, by the way.

Comment: @jazzurro it does not save it, it is the strangest thing happened to me so far. Please call it with for example my.lis <- and then you remove the last part as you suggest then invoke the list. You see that it does not save it because it gets error

Comment: Pierre just dropped an answer for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the internal selfref works when you remove it wherever it pops up. If the resulting list has many instances, you can use the find-replace feature in RStudio. For more on why this occurs [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533332/cannot-use-dput-for-data-table-in-r/25533592#25533592)

```
list(structure(list(check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                                        FALSE), myfile = c("", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R11]", "1xOxidation [M7]", 
                                                           "", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R11]", ""), Myname = c("Q9Y383", "Q9Y383", 
                                                                                                             "Q9Y383", "Q15366-2", "Q15366-2", "Q15366-2")), .Names = c("check", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "myfile", "Myname"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "data.frame")), structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ), myfile = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Myname = c("F8W727", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "O76021", "P46783", "P35527", "Q96C45", "Q9Y383", "Q9Y383"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 )), .Names = c("check", "myfile", "Myname"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            -7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")), 
               structure(list(check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                                        FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), myfile = c("", 
                                                                                              "", "", "", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R7]", "", "", "", "3xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R1; R7; R10]", 
                                                                                              "", ""), Myname = c("P61247", "P39019", "Q9NWH9", "P62917", 
                                                                                                                  "P62917", "E9PCT1", "Q15149", "Q14152", "Q14152", "Q15020", 
                                                                                                                  "Q02543")), .Names = c("check", "myfile", "Myname"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     -11L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))

# [[1]]
#   check                     myfile   Myname
# 1 FALSE                              Q9Y383
# 2 FALSE 1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R11]   Q9Y383
# 3 FALSE           1xOxidation [M7]   Q9Y383
# 4 FALSE                            Q15366-2
# 5 FALSE 1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R11] Q15366-2
# 6 FALSE                            Q15366-2
# 
# [[2]]
#   check myfile Myname
# 1 FALSE     NA F8W727
# 2 FALSE     NA O76021
# 3 FALSE     NA P46783
# 4 FALSE     NA P35527
# 5 FALSE     NA Q96C45
# 6 FALSE     NA Q9Y383
# 7 FALSE     NA Q9Y383
# 
# [[3]]
#    check                             myfile Myname
# 1  FALSE                                    P61247
# 2  FALSE                                    P39019
# 3  FALSE                                    Q9NWH9
# 4  FALSE                                    P62917
# 5  FALSE          1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R7] P62917
# 6  FALSE                                    E9PCT1
# 7  FALSE                                    Q15149
# 8  FALSE                                    Q14152
# 9  FALSE 3xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R1; R7; R10] Q14152
# 10 FALSE                                    Q15020
# 11 FALSE                                    Q02543
```

Comment: [See this question for more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533332/cannot-use-dput-for-data-table-in-r/25533592#25533592). I will link this question to that one for future searchers.

Comment: would you mind to look at my original question too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039915/how-can-i-manipulate-a-very-large-list

Comment: You are misguided in requesting someone to produce your exact output when it isn't correct. You added extra `NA` values to the second data table and add blank spaces to the rest. Asking for someone to produce inconsistent results requires extra programming that most people do not want to waste time with.

Comment: what should I do then? if someone even give me a hint how to go to solve it, I can try to do it. also I can like and accept an answer or I don't know what else i must do,

Comment: Don't ask for someone to produce the "exact" result that you have. Just ask someone to help get to the general idea.

Comment: You are going from someone asking for advice to a boss wanting an assignment completed to the 't'.

Comment: sure, I removed it and believe me it is not an assignment  I have been working on it since last night but I could not figure it out

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

It works if you remove the `.internal.selfref` part of the `dput` in the last line:

```
my.list<- list(structure(list(check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), myfile = c("", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R11]", "1xOxidation [M7]", "", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R11]", ""), Myname = c("Q9Y383", "Q9Y383", "Q9Y383", "Q15366-2", "Q15366-2", "Q15366-2")), .Names = c("check", "myfile", "Myname"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103006b78>), structure(list(check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), myfile = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Myname = c("F8W727","O76021", "P46783", "P35527", "Q96C45", "Q9Y383", "Q9Y383")), .Names = c("check", "myfile", "Myname"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103006b78>), structure(list(check = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), myfile = c("","", "", "", "1xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R7]", "", "", "", "3xLabel:13C(6)15N(4) [R1; R7; R10]", "", ""), Myname = c("P61247", "P39019", "Q9NWH9", "P62917","P62917", "E9PCT1", "Q15149", "Q14152", "Q14152", "Q15020","Q02543")), .Names = c("check", "myfile", "Myname"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You have to erase it in three places since there are three data tables

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune I did it but did not work, can you please give me a solution ?

Comment: There's nothing else to add. Erase `, .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103006b78>` in the three places it exists and it will work. I can verify that this does work.