# dput() without .internal.selfref in data tables

Tags: r, data.table

Someone recently shared their data table with me via `dput()` and an error popped up that I had not previously encountered:

> Error: unexpected '<' in:
> "          class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
> .internal.selfref = <"

After some digging I found this is [related specifically to data.tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533332/cannot-use-dput-for-data-table-in-r) and as advised in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042358/dput-of-a-list-is-giving-error?noredirect=1&lq=1), removing the `internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fd60e036ce0>)` did the trick to successfully assign their data.

However, I anticipate sharing these types of data frequently between novice users; I have not found a reasonable/sustainable solution to prevent this from exporting with the `dput`, only ad-hoc functions and/or removing it after receiving running it.

If I remove `showAttributes` from the `control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger", "niceNames", "showAttributes")` in `dput` the `.internal.selfref` is gone but so is everything else about the structure.

The questions and answers provided in the above linked questions were 5-9 years old; I was hoping that some improved functionality may be available (that I am obviously unaware of) that would tell `dput` to ignore this, or perhaps if there is something I can do to the data table itself before `dput` that would remove the `.internal.selfref` altogether.

**Is there a way to provide the `dput` of a `data.table` object without producing the `.internal.selfref`?**

Thanks in advance.

Example of the issue:

```
dattab <- data.table::data.table(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
dput(dattab)

structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 6:10), row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
          class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
          .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fd60e036ce0>)
```

Comment: Is it really critical to pass all the attributes to your users?  And if so,  probably just take the output of the  customized `dput` and  use `gsub` or similar tool to remove the ".internal.selfref*>"  (not actual regex code) part.

Comment: Have you considered using `saveRDS` instead of `dput`? Not sure how you are sharing, but this will create a physical copy that you can share.

Comment: since you are sharing the data, i would suggest you remove the selfref before you share

Comment: Thanks all - I suppose alternative approaches will need to be used here (i.e. rds). I considered a bounty but respectfully don't think it is the same question - the other question is framed at "how can one import with this?", and the accepted solution provides the "delete after" approach. Since data sharing will be both ways in my case, this was more targeted to the question "how can one export without this" - not simply solve-at-any-cost. C'est la vie - if the experts (y'all) think so, we'll be best to look into alternative approaches!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes I think it's useful to share it with the appropriate class, so I use this function:

```r
#' dput into a single line
#'
#' @param x object
#' @param assign logical, whether to get the 'x' object's name and
#'   prepend it to the string
#' @param DT logical, whether to remove (and wrap with 'setDT')
#'   'internal.selfref' in the dput output
#' @return character length 1, invisibly
#' @export
r2dput <- function(x, assign = TRUE, DT = TRUE) {
  out <- deparse1(x)
  if (isTRUE(DT)) {
    out2 <- gsub(",\\s*\\.internal\\.selfref\\s*=\\s*<pointer:\\s*[0-9a-fx]+>", "", out)
    if (out != out2) {
      out <- paste0("data.table::as.data.table(", out2, ")")
    }
  }
  if (assign) {
    out <- paste(c(as.character(substitute(x)), "<-", out), collapse = " ")
  }
  if (R.version$os == "mingw32") {
    writeLines(out, con = "clipboard")
  } else {
    clipr::write_clip(out)
  }
  invisible(out)
}
```

As an example,

```r
MT <- as.data.table(mtcars[1:3, 11:4])
MT
#     carb  gear    am    vs  qsec    wt  drat    hp
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     4     4     1     0 16.46 2.620  3.90   110
# 2:     4     4     1     0 17.02 2.875  3.90   110
# 3:     1     4     1     1 18.61 2.320  3.85    93
```

When I want to share that data in a question on SO (or with colleagues), I type in `r2dput(MT)` (because, you know, I'm r2evans ;-), I just paste (`Ctrl-V`) into the comment/question/answer and get this:

```r
MT <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(carb = c(4, 4, 1), gear = c(4, 4, 4), am = c(1, 1, 1), vs = c(0, 0, 1), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61), wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32), drat = c(3.9, 3.9, 3.85), hp = c(110, 110, 93)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

This removes the `pointer` that doesn't work, it wraps in `as.data.table(.)` making it clear what class I'm really working with, and keeps it all on one line (because I dislike the default `dput` method of line-breaks in formatted code blocks).

(Edited to use `clipr` on non-windows. I'm not sure it works the same on macos.)

Comment: Very nice helper function.

Comment: (@DirkEddelbuettel, I have several such helper functions for working with and around Stack questions, it seems ...)

Comment: I'm curious, though, I _just_ updated the code a few minutes ago, what brought you to look at this page, if I may ask? The timing is rather coincidental @DirkEddelbuettel

Comment: When you edit it re-appears at the top-level page. I saw the topic, and looked at the question.  You may know about my `dang` package of such helpers. Feel to contribute (under full attribution etc ie add yourself to contributor list in DESCRIPTION).  For this one, I think `dtdput` may be a nice name. I would remove the clipboard business though.  Stdout is fine.  But if you want to keep the paste that is fine too.  You have the helper you need and want.

Comment: I did _not_ know about `dang`, I'll take a look. (I'm particularly fond of the clipboard action, tbh, since larger sample data is textual clutter, and large-large samples tend to clobber and slow-down emacs/ess some. So I just try to keep my console "tidy" (in the uncluttered way).)

Comment: We all have our own ways. It's all good.  I don't even think I have ever done `library(clipr)`.

Answer (score 6):

Convert the data.table to a data.frame and then `dput` it.

```
dput(as.data.frame(dattab))
## structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 6:10), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Then presumably the  either the OP or his target audience needs to write  `newdattab <-  as.data.table(dput(as.data.frame(dattab)))`

Answer (score 3):

Consider the {constructive} package, it's pretty much always better than `dput()` especially for Stack Overflow.

```r
library(constructive)
dattab <- data.table::data.table(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
MT <- data.table::as.data.table(mtcars[1:3, 11:4])

construct(dattab)
#> data.table::data.table(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)

construct(MT)
#> data.table::data.table(
#>   carb = c(4, 4, 1),
#>   gear = rep(4, 3L),
#>   am = rep(1, 3L),
#>   vs = c(0, 0, 1),
#>   qsec = c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61),
#>   wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32),
#>   drat = c(3.9, 3.9, 3.85),
#>   hp = c(110, 110, 93)
#> )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `attr` to set the attributes of the `data.table` object

##### Data

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(1:3, 2:4)

dput(dt)
structure(list(V1 = 1:3, V2 = 2:4), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55f7f168fef0>)
```

##### Function

```
DTput <- function(x){attr(x, which = ".internal.selfref") <- NULL; dput(x)}
```

##### Use

```
DTput(dt)
structure(list(V1 = 1:3, V2 = 2:4), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```